# In Android okhttpclient not caching public cache-control

Tags: android, header, private, cache-control

1. I am using below code to cache in Android device to collect the response and get from cache till the max age expires. When i use "public" I was able to see the response cached in my application installed folder(/data/data/app_folder).
2. I tried all below none of them works for "private" but when I change to "public" all my solutions i tried works.
3. But I need to make it to work for "private". Am I missing something.
4. Header I will receive "Cache-Control", "private,max-age=120"

## Solution 1:

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "responses");

HttpResponseCache httpResponseCache = null;
try {
        httpResponseCache = new HttpResponseCache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Retrofit", "Could not create http cache", e);
    }

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setResponseCache(httpResponseCache);
```

## Solution 2:

1. And I am using Retrofit library, an Android client.

   ```
   Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);    
   client = new OkHttpClient();
   client.setCache(cache);
   ```

Comment: In your question title you mention that `public` does not get cached, but in your question body you say that `private` causes a problem. Can you clarify which `Cache-Control` setting is not working for you?

Comment: You are right. Title should say "In Android okhttpclient not caching private cache-control" thanks for point out.