# Can I stop HTTPResponseCache behaving like a shared cache in regard to Cache-Control headers?

Tags: android, http, caching, cache-control, httpresponsecache

I am trying to use the built in `HTTPResponseCache` in my app (making requests via the `HTTPURLConnection` API) but am having problems trying to get it to cache any responses that were requested with an `Authorization` header included.

The only way I can get it to cache the response at *all* is to explicitly put 'public' in the `Cache-Control` response header on the server (`s-maxage` might work too, haven't tried, but explicitly putting `private` results in no caching); but this will mean that any intermediate proxies will cache the response to serve to other clients, which is not what I want.

My understanding is that a user agent cache would cache responses requested with `Authorization` headers by default or with a `private` header. It seems like the `HTTPResponseCache` is acting like a shared cache in how it is interpreting the headers, rather than a user agent cache. Or is my understanding of the caching standards not correct?

Is there any way I can get the cache to act like a user agent HTTP cache?

This in my install code:

```
public static void setupCache(Context context, long httpCacheSize){
  File httpCacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"http");
  HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
}
```

Do I need to do something different here? Or perhaps I need to include some user agent information in my requests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (unanswered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435766/in-android-okhttpclient-not-caching-public-cache-control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I found no solution to this specific issue, I worked around my problem by refactoring my HTTP client code to use Volley (http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) rather than HTTPURLConnection. The caching facilities in Volley are implemented separately to HTTPResponseCache and implement handling of cache control headers as expected for a user agent cache.